# How to block other apps?

Tags: java, android

I've seen a lot of parental control & productivity apps that can block you from certain apps you wish by asking you permission for user access when installing. How exactly do they do that, any help or related info is appreciated

Comment: Yeah, you can start by reading [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those apps simply check for the current running tasks and then kill their activities.

```
    public class TaskChecker{
    public static String getForegroundApplication(Context context){
        ActivityManager am=(ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        RunningTaskInfo foreground=am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);
        return foreground.topActivity.getPackageName();
    }
}
```

That piece of code simply checks the current running and see's whether it's an activity or not. This is how you'd block WhatsApp using that code

```
String currentRunningApp = TaskChecker.getForegroundApplication(yourContext);

if(currentRunningApp.equals("com.whatsapp")){
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)yourContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);    

    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    this.startActivity(startMain);

    am.killBackgroundProcesses(currentRunningApp );
}
```

PS you'd need the following permissions and make sure you run it from a service every minute or so

```
<android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS">
<android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES">
```

Comment: Peace be with you, I've edited my solution :)